# Trigger exec_pull on http connection

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp

Is it possible to trigger `exec_pull` on **http** connection? For example, I have the following **Nginx** configuration:

```
server {

 listen 80;

location /hls {

  types {
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
    video/mp2t ts;
  }

                  root /mnt;
                  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
                  index index.m3u8 index.ts;
                  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            }
        }

}

rtmp {

    server {
        listen 1935;
        allow play all;

application hls {

live on;
exec_options on;

exec_pull /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i http://example.com:333/293.m3u8 -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name;
}

application hls {

    live on;
    hls on;
    hls_path /mnt/hls;
    hls_fragment 3s;
}

     }
  }
```

I would like to have an `exec_pull` triggered on HLS http request.
For example If I request http://my-serverip.com/hls/293.m3u8 then it should start ffmpeg to start creating `hls` files.

I've been working on this for 5-6 days and could not figure out how to trigger `exec_pull` on http requests.

Comment: Hi. Any luck on this? I have the same issue.